# iOS: Date formatter with "ar_AE" language code not converting date to Arabic

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

When I try to convert date to Arabic language with below code & `ar_AE` language code, it shows date in western numerals  not in Arabic.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "ar_AE")
lblDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Output:

[image]

once I change the language code / local identifier to `ar_OM` or `ar_SD` or any other arabic countries it works in iOS.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "ar_OM")
lblDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Output:

[image]

Tested on `iOS 15.5` & `13.3`, there is nothing related to iOS version.

Also `ar_AE` shows dates in Arabic in `Android` & https://nsdateformatter.com/

Request someone to help me to understand the reason why "`ar_AE`" code is not working while if I provide identifier "`ar`" it works perfectly & that would be great help if we can resolve this.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean here by "not working?" Do you have a source (or personal experience in-country) that indicates YYYY/MM/DD with western numerals is an incorrect medium date format in UAE? Different countries have different preferences for these things. The long format for UAE uses western numerals and Arabic month name. My assumption is that western numerals are commonly used in UAE. Do you believe that's not true?

Comment: All the numerals on the UAE's official site in Arabic are western: https://u.ae/ar-ae#/  I don't see any medium dates, but their long dates match what Apple's `.long` formatter does. Even better example in Arabic: https://u.ae/ar-ae/about-the-uae/history

Comment: @RobNapier That's the requirement hence the date must be present in arabic. Thanks for your comment & time. ar_AE is the valid code but I am not getting any particular document as a proof that iOS shows the date for this code in western numerals.

Comment: I would say that Apple has intentionally decided that western numerals are correct for `ar_AE` (and that matches my research on what UAE websites use for themselves in Arabic). If you have reason to believe that this is not culturally correct for users in UAE, you should open a Feedback and discuss it. If you want some non-standard behavior, you'll need to create a custom Locale that behaves the way you expect. (see "Creating custom locales from components" in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale) Ultimately, you'll probably need to switch `ar_AE` to `ar`

Comment: Thanks for your time @RobNapier, resolved as per your last comment only.